# Is a JSON response always an object?

Tags: android, json

I was wondering if the response coming from an API is always an object? I'm consuming data from an API that's been updated, the response format has changed. Previously I was getting an array of objects and would map it to a List using Gson but now I'm getting an object with an array and some other strings. I want to know if what I was getting before was just an array or it was still an object.

**First I was dealing with this:**

```
[
    {
      "id": 1 
      "name": "john"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2 
      "name": "jack"
    }

]
```

**and now:**

```
{
   "users": [],
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusMessage": "success",
}
```

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) is a text encoding of some data structure. It can be a primitive type (string, number, boolean, null) or a complex type (array or object). The API service is free to return any data type as long as it is properly encoded as JSON.

Comment: arrays and objects are different structures Sounds like what you had before was an array containing some objects, and now you've got an object containing an array (which may itself still contain some other objects, arrays or primitives). So pretty much exactly what you said. If you're not sure, you could always show us a sample of each.

Comment: You need to use model class to map .

Comment: @axiac so basically the answer is no?

Comment: @ADyson I'm getting exactly that I don't have access to the previous for but it's what you said. Now I have re-model my model classes, right?

Comment: if you're trying to deserialise to a specific object structure, unfortunately yes you do.

Comment: @ADyson yes I do

Comment: @ADyson I've added an example.

Comment: `[
 "user1": {}
 "user2": {}
 "user3": {}
]` is not valid JSON. Array items don't have names. I doubt this was your real structure. No JSON deserialiser would be able to read that.

Comment: @ADyson sorry I had something else in mind, I've fixed the example.

Comment: Ok. So yes the first example is an array, the second is an object. I'd hazard a guess that the "users" property in the second example is an array containing objects in the same structure as the array in the first example? In which case all you'd need to do is add another class to represent the outer object you're now receiving, you can re-use the Users class you (presumably) had before to represent the items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Json responses can be a collection of name/value pairs which means an **object**. Also, this response can be an ordered list of values which means an **array**.

ref:
https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't well-defined because there is no single obvious interpretation of "object" in this context. The following devolves into a *"yeah but, no but, yeah but"* discussion which however hopefully at least allows you to draw a tentative "yes" or "no" conclusion depending on what you actually mean. (If you are in a hurry, maybe scroll down to the horizontal line, or search down for "regardless".)

**No,** a JSON response is simply an UTF-8 string with some fomatting constraints. `"500 Internal server error"` is valid JSON (because of the double quotes), as is `{"hovercraft": ["eel", "eel", "eel", "eel"]}`. See http://json.org/ for the full specification.

But **yes,** strings are objects in some programming languages, such as Javascript and Python; though **no,** they aren't in many others, like Perl and Lisp. Low-level languages like asm and C don't even *have* objects. Anyway, this is almost certainly not what you mean, so mainly just an academic digression.

As the name says, JSON is a JavaScript Object Notation format, though it is long since divorced from the JavaScript language. So **yes,** by definition, a JSON string encodes a serialization of something which is referred to as an object; though on the other hand, **no,** the serialization itself *isn't* that object. Compare how the string `"123"` can be parsed into the integer 123, but (in most languages) is a distinct representation with a different type on which you can perform operations like `length()` and `substring(i,j)` which don't make much sense on a number; whereas numeric operations like subtraction and division are not well-defined or even possible to perform on strings in many languages.

For an API to make sense, the sender and receiver need to agree on the semantics of a message. JSON alone doesn't implement this. It only transfers the contents of a structured container, not the full object in the form of a class with methods. So **no,** this isn't the full object; the API implementation still needs to exist separately in both the sender and receiver. But on the other hand, if this is a given, then **yes,** all that is needed to reinstantiate a communicated object is in the object's JSON serialization.

*Probably* at least either the client or the server is written in a language which uses classes with methods to support object-oriented programming. In this case, **yes,** that implementation probably converts the JSON serialization into an object internally, and more or less transparently. But the same logic could be written in C where this representation most probably becomes a `struct` and the programmer needs to take care of enforcing the integrity of the representation etc; though on the other hand, you could argue that this *is* an object and that moving the burden of managing the memory and running only the correct methods onto the programmer's shoulders is an implementation detail. (The history of programming languages would have this the other way around; but it's not outrageous to argue that OOP semantics are a plausible reference model even for languages which aren't object-oriented.)

---

Regardless of whether you land in "yes" or "no" land, both the responses in your question are valid JSON structures. If one is an object, so is the other. (Though only the former is an array of structures, if that's more specifically what you were expecting or hoping for.) Quite regardless, changing an API to return a completely different structure than before is certainly not best current practice.

(Best current practice would be to change the URL for the new version of the API, and probably keep the old version alive at the old URL in parallel for some time.)

Comment: His quesion is unclear, but your reply for an unclear question is a bible-size way too long.